# Occasional WiFi blips

Tags: networking, router

I'm attempting to track down some weirdness involving Internet blips. These blips are weird because they are there and then they are gone, so if you miss them you're fine. If you happen to be browsing or gaming during them then you'll notice. For example, in a browser you'll find it'll stop at trying to do some TLS stuff. If you're in World of Warcraft you'll find everyone else can move except you --or-- the reverse. So I'm left thinking that this part is up to how the app handles the networking troubles.

I previously had cable (copper) and all the wiring was new.
After troubles I went fiber and have FTTP (Fiber straight into my house with a transceiver and everything). Same issues. So it's not the provider. Provider also gave us their own router -- so I've tried 2 different WiFi devices and three different routers. I doubt it's those.

Issue persists across iOS, Android, Roku, Windows 10, MacOS. So it's not the OS.

It also happens on WiFi and Cat5e (from router). So it's not something hokey in the air.

I've removed all devices but one to test to make sure it wasn't a device spending gibberish across the network that was being broadcasted. So it's not a singular device.

So my only observations, so far, is when the A/C kicks off -- the issues *usually* go away.

I've noticed that it also happens without the A/C on sometimes.
I purchased a digital multi-meter to plug into the power outlets but so far it's 118-123v. So it doesn't seem to be power however every now and then the lights get very bright -- making me question our wiring in the house.

I don't know what to try next. I've tried, literally, everything I can think of.

Comment: Did you change ISPs when you went from copper to fiber?

Comment: Yes from Spectrum (formerly Time Warner) to AT&T.

Comment: Ok, I got an AC power conditioner as well as EM/RFI cleaning. I read something somewhere saying that my air conditioner could interfere with the power maybe.